# Can't suggest an edit or flag the missing image, because the post is locked

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, suggested-edits, flagging

It seems there is no possibility to suggest an edit or flag the missing image when the post is locked. Is that a bug or feature?

Here is the [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227/21471).

Despite image is hosted at stack.imgur.com server, it has been removed for some reason. There is [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130514191409/https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1GI.png) from 2013, but it doesn't work either.

Related SE meta post: [Unable to flag posts on historically locked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129550/191655).

Comment: That's correct, when a Q&A gets locked like that, it's generally because the Q is not actually a good question, however it's existed for some period of time and accrued answers which have some value, so rather than delete everything, it's "locked" as the banner mentions, and kept for historical reasons, but is no longer allowed to be edited or answered etc. In rare cases such as this using meta or the chat room for U&L are the best options.

Comment: WRT the image, I'm unable to find a archived version of it either. I'll keep looking but if we cannot find one, I can remove the broken link from that A'er.

Answer (score 4):

It is a feature.  The point of locking a post is to keep it from being developed by the community (edits, answers, anything) until the author fixes whatever rules it violates.

It sucks when there is something uncontroversially wrong (grammar, spelling, broken link, etc), but the pros outweigh the cons.

Comment: I think *favs* can still be developed.